# How can I stop jquery position div from rolling over footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jquery script that is used to help flow mydiv down the page. It works great! however, it is overflowing my  how can i stop it so it doesn't overflow the footer?

**html**

```
<div id="follow">
    <div class="summaryTotal">
        <h3>Estimated Total </h3>           
        <h3 class="summary" data-price="0">$0</h3>
        <span class="small">Read more about our pricing here.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        <h3>Quote:</h3>
        <ul id="selections"></ul>
</div>
    <button type="submit" class="button-success">Book Now!</button>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('book/services') }}" class="button-error">Start over</a>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
</div>
<br />

<footer>blah vlah</footer>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var speed = 1000;
    var current_top = parseInt( $('#follow').css('top') );
    $(window).scroll( function () {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#follow').css('top', top + current_top);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#follow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You should prepare a small, functional example of what you are trying to do using http://jsfiddle.net -- this will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry here ya go. See how it overflows on the footer? http://jsfiddle.net/8pkE7/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by overflows the footer?

Comment: The well div's go over the top of the footer tag. I need it to stop right before it hits the footer tag

Comment: As far as I can tell, this jsfiddle is not functional. The divs do not scroll, let alone "overflow the footer." Can you please post completely valid HTML so that the example does what you are saying it does

Comment: works fine on my end. http://i.imgur.com/WoLdaDS.png